# Stopping abuse of the postal service? How to bring change?

Tags: leadership

My company mails about 300 letters a day to our clients and an additional 50 thank you cards whenever the CEO decides to go on a tree killing bender. The postal service has to deal with all this every day and I want to help the postman. How can I convince my company to not send out this mail?

I am a software engineer on a project team. I just see the letters going out every day from the secretary.

Comment: Why what do you mean, "want to help the postman?". It's their job. It's like taking your friends to a restaurant and then making sure they don't order food cause it inconveniences the chef.

Comment: You're worrying about something that isn't your responsibility. If you want to save trees, move away from paper reports and make things electronic. PDF, dashboards, real-time reports, etc.

Comment: If you want to help your local post person you should encourage this. Paper mail is WAY down and most postal services survive only through shipping spam & junk mail. If that stops, many post people will loose their jobs.

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that this is a real question-- the postal system is designed to allow companies to send letters to customers.  Using the postal system in the way it was intended is the opposite of abuse.

If you want to change some process, you'll want to make a business case.  The first question to ask is what benefit the company derives (or expects to derive) from the current process.  Are these letters advertising?  Reminders?  Something else?  Then determine an alternative that produces the same benefit for a lower cost and make a case for this alternative.  I, for example, am quite happy that my broker lets me opt in to receiving my annual mutual fund prospectuses electronically rather than getting hundreds of pages of paper mailed to me every year that get discarded almost immediately.  Perhaps you could suggest building a system that allowed customers to opt to receive some or all of this mail electronically for example.